# Changing background colors in a specific sequence with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am building out a masonry grid which is 3 columns.  I need for each grid item to have a background color applied to it via CSS, but in a specific order:

- Blue, green pink
- Green, pink, blue
- Pink, blue, green
- (repeat)

I have tried the following, but it doesn't quite get me there:

```
.masonry_item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: blue;
}
.masonry_item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background: green;
}
.masonry_item:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: pink;
}
```

Here is a simplified version of the HTML:

```
<div class="masonry_container">
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add HTML template here?

Comment: I went ahead and added that into the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern repeat each 9 elements not 3.

```css
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+1),
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+6),
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+8){
  background: blue;
}
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+2),
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+4),
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+9){
  background: green;
}
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+3),
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+5),
.masonry_item:nth-child(9n+7){
  background: pink;
}


.masonry_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry_container">
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
  <div class="masonry_item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using :even and :odd pseudo-classes